# MOUT course score

Tags: americas-army-3

What score do I need to get to get basic on the MOUT Course training? Proficient? Expert?

Comment: is this AA:O or AA3?

Comment: this is about AA3

Comment: AA was amazing, I'm glad they've decided to make another one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from [this thread](http://americasarmy.hu/info/info.php?m=p&i=Training&p=9&sid=_sid_):

**Basic**

- Time: <= 270 and > 210 seconds
- Soldier Profile Field: BCTMOUTLevel = 1
- BCTMOUTDate set t - current UTC date/time
- Honor Increase (all attributes) +60

**Proficient**

- Time: <= 210 and > 150 seconds
- Soldier Profile Field: BCTMOUTLevel = 2
- BCTMOUTDate set t - current UTC date/time
- Honor Increase (all attributes) +66

**Expert**

- Time: <= 150
- Soldier Profile Field: BCTMOUTLevel = 3
- BCTMOUTDate set t - current UTC date/time
- Honor Increase (all attributes) +72
- MA_ExpertInfantrymanBadge achievement set t - 1 (and MA_ExpertInfantrymanBadgeDate set t - current date/time)
  Retries that improve will result in gaining the difference between the tw - “Honor Increase” values.

**MOUT Target Scoring**

MOUT Scoring is comprised of several factors as listed below:

- Number of targets missed (target hit location is not considered s - a hit anywhere on a target is considered valid). Each missed target results in a 10 second penalty.
- Number of “friendly” (ROE Events) targets hit. Each friendly target hit adds a 15 second penalty.
- Number of enemy targets "confirmed". Each target confirmed results in one second deducted from the total time.
- Incorrect smoke usage results in a 60 second time penalty
- Not destroying target adds a 60 second time penalty
- Flashbang usage does not affect the total time directly, but will stop the in-game timers and result in a lower overall time
- An invalid treatment of the SIMMAN patient results in a 60 second time penalty
- Total time through the course (as shown by the in-game timer)
  At the completion of the training the penalties are added t - the total time and any confirmation bonuses are subtracted t - generate the final time.

The key is watching the timer, as it only runs between two beeps. Move and aim fast while time's ticking. The timer will stop after completing each section/room which is shooting all hostile targets, after which you can take your time to confirm all.

4:30 should be doable, as far as I remember getting it done under 2 minutes with maximum 1 missed targets should net you the Expert badge.

Hooah, soldier!